# A problem in Analysis that comes up in Erick Weinberg's book, 'Classical Solutions in quantum field theory'

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\rho$ is a function of $x$ and $\rho\geq0$ and $(\rho')^2 - \rho''\rho\geq 1$ I need to prove that $\rho$ has at least one zero. Some of the things that I have been able to is that $\rho$ cannot have a minimum anywhere (in the given range for $\rho$ above). I also tried a proof by contradiction. Say $\rho$ does not have any zero. Then the inequality can be rewritten as $-\rho^2 (\frac{\rho'}{\rho})'\leq 1$ But not sure how this helps too. Can anyone help me prove this.

Answer (score 2):

If $\rho(a)=0$, then $|\rho'(a)|\ge1$. This implies that $\rho$ takes negative values either to the right or left of $a$, contradicting the fact that $\rho\ge0$.

Comment: Could you expand on the part of $|\rho'(a)| \ge1\Rightarrow \rho$ takes negative values?

Comment: Let's say $\rho(a)\ge1$ ($>0$ is enough.) Since $\rho$ is continuous (because $\rho''$ exists) $\rho$ is strictly increasing on a neighborhood of $a$. This implies $\rho(x)<0$ on $(a-\epsilon,a)$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Your observation is correct. In fact after proving this, the aim is to determine a range of $x$ between two zero's of $\rho$ for those $\rho$'s that admit 2 zeros.. So as an example for $\rho=C sin(x)$ we then fix the range of $x$ to be $[0,\pi]$. We set the first zero to be at $x=0$ by hand. However, before that I need to first prove that given the inequality above $\rho$ has at least one zero. That is the problem I want to solve.

Comment: My answer shows it is impossible if you insist on $\rho\ge0$, something your example $C\sin x$ does not satisfy.